# How to implement tinymce in vue in a way eslint doesn't throw "tinymce is not defined error"?

Tags: vue.js, tinymce, eslint

I'm trying to make tinymce and eslint work together in a vue app, but every time I try to use something like `tinymce.activeEditor...`, eslint throws the error `'tinymce' is not defined` when building.
If I disable eslint, the app is built fine and I can use `tinymce.activeEditor...` normally.
Since tinymce is get from the cloud, how can I define it inside the app to avoid eslint throwing that error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be clear what you are seeing is simply that `eslint` - based on how it is configured - does not want you to reference undefined variables.   This is not a TinyMCE issue per se but likely relevant if you are using TinyMCE Cloud to load TinyMCE as your JavaScript code is not defining a `tinymce` variable.

There are a few ways you could choose to "fix" `eslint` complaining:

1 - Access `tinymce` through the global window object:

```
window.tinymce
```

2 - Wrap your code with a directive for eslint to not check for undefined variables:

```
/*eslint-disable no-undef*/
...
/*eslint-enable no-undef*/
```

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments

3 - Define a global in your `.eslintrc` file

```
{
  "globals": {
    "tinymce": true
  }
}
```

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals

Answer (score 0):

4 - To add the special comment at the file beginning.

```
/* global tinymce, _, wpLink */
```